# I don’t understand what “ps ho lstart 1” and how to “configure highlight color”

Tags: bash

Been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236640/15603477) answer.
for this command `ps ho lstart 1`.  So I am not sure `ho` and `1` mean.

Is possible to easily configure highlight color when display search matched result?

```
ps - report a snapshot of the current processes.
lstart -     STARTED   time the command started.  See also bsdstart, start, start_time, and stime.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter consists of the `h` and `o` options.

Very old Unix commands used to handle options without a leading dash (this can still be seen in `tar`). Also, the `ps` command evolved differently in BSD and SysV Unix families, both variants growing different options, and the Linux `ps` accepts *both* kinds of options – distinguished by whether they are prefixed by a dash or not. In this case, options without a dash are interpreted as "BSD" options. (Nowadays, BSD ps accepts a dash too.)

```
DESCRIPTION
       This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:

       1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
       2   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
       3   GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.
```

The two options are:

```
       h      No header.  (or, one header per screen in the BSD personality).
```

```
       o format
              Specify user-defined format.  Identical to -o and --format.
```

This indicates that the *second* word – the one following the `o` – is an argument to the `o` option, and contains a list of columns to display. In this case it specifies only one column, the `LSTART` field.

Finally, the third word doesn't belong to any options, so it is interpreted as a PID – specifically, process ID `1` is the *init* process, which has been running since the system was booted.

```
PROCESS SELECTION BY LIST

       123    Identical to --pid 123.
```

The result is that the command shows one column of information for one specific PID.

Comment: Hi, @user1686  Can you help me with this question?  >> https://superuser.com/questions/1695194/character-length-bash-print-evaluation-hard-to-understand